# Why is there a PostFixture in the cakephp core?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.6

I wanted to add a blog to my cakephp 2.6.13 installation and named the table `Post`. After I was done with everything I ran the tests and discovered, that they fail.

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class PostFixture in /var/www/gutscheinpony/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/lib/Cake/Test/Fixture/PostFixture.php on line 51

Can I run my tests with the name `Post` or do I have to pick another name?

If not, why is there a PostFixture in the core anyway?
https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.6.13/lib/Cake/Test/Fixture/PostFixture.php

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out why this happend.
You can load your own fixtures using `app.post` in your test cases and `core.post` to load the core fixtures.
For some reason one of the plugins I use called the core fixture and caused the issue.